# Is there a way to print or log variable values in a udf function in bigquery?

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery, udf

I have both sql and udf functions that work fine together.

I want to compare record's date which is an integer and has yyyymmdd format and today's date in my determineText() function.

Is there a method like console.log() or document.write() in order to print a variable's value in a udf function in bigquery ?

**my udf functions :**

```
function myUdfFunction(row, emit) {

 text = determineText(row.localdate);
 emit({point_id: row.point_id, text: text});
}

function determineText(dateInteger){
  var resultText = "";
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

  if(dd<10) {
      dd='0'+dd
  } 

  if(mm<10) {
      mm='0'+mm
  } 


  today = yyyy + mm + dd;
  today = parseInt(today);
  //console.log("today : "+today+"\ndateInteger : "+dateInteger); // not working
  if (today == dateInteger)
    resultText = "Okay";
  else
    resultText = "Not Okay";

  return resultText;
}


bigquery.defineFunction(
 'myUdfFunction',// Name of the function exported to SQL
 ['point_id', 'min_weight', 'localdate', 'temp_min', 'temp_max', 'precipitation', 'lat', 'lng'],// Names of input columns
 // Output schema 
 [{'name': 'point_id', 'type': 'integer'},  
  {'name': 'text', 'type': 'string'}],
 myUdfFunction// Reference to JavaScript UDF
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions#limitations

> The DOM objects Window, Document and Node, and functions that require them, are unsupported.

Still, what you need - can be easily accomplished by
1. testing your UDF outside of BigQuery or,
2. if for some reason you need test you UDF from within BigQuery, you can use **emit** function to output anything as a output's fields

Comment: What do you mean by the `emit` function? I couldn't find any reference in BigQuery on this.

Comment: This was in Legacy BigQuery SQL